# UIPageViewController setViewControllers, UIPageControl not showing right current number

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'am using a UIPageViewController with horizontal scrolling... as long as the user scrolls, the UIPageControl works correctly, problem occurs when jumping programmatically to next or previous page

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerWithIndex:index]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Than the index of the UIPageControl isn't right (i would provide the index by myself, but cannot access the UIPageViewController's UIPageControl)

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return IntroScreensCount;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 0;
}
```

**How to get the current dot index of the UIPageControl right, when changing the UIPageViewController page programmatically?**

Comment: show your delegate methods

Comment: edited, but the delegates have nothing to do with it, as they only provide min and max index, not the current one

Comment: ok, now i'am getting it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, turned out that i misunderstood one delegate method

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return [(IntroPageViewController *)[pageViewController.viewControllers firstObject] index];
}
```