# UIPageControl and UIPageviewController are out of sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController that shows 7 pages.

I've noticed this weird issue: Whenever you swipe the page controller and tap the Uipagecontrol, which is at the bottom, in the opposite direction of the swipe at the same time the page that is currently being displayed and the page number in the pagecontrol will be out of sync. Does anyone have this weird issue and solved it. Please help me. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Please post some code and perhaps a video or screenshot.

Comment: @Roecrew: Sorry i couldn't add a video or screenshot as my app is Proprietary. But i fixed my problem by hiding the UIPageViewController's Page Control and added a separate UIPageControl to my UIViewController and updating the Page Number of the UIPageControl whenever the user goes to a different page.

Comment: I seem to have run into the same problem. And I've tried multiple UIPageViewController examples online. And they did al display this odd behaviour. Swiping fast and tapping fast on the page control will get them out of sync. - It seems those examples did not correctly show the method presentationIndexForViewController. Implementing it correctly fixes the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406833/uipageviewcontroller-setviewcontrollers-uipagecontrol-not-showing-right-current?rq=1